# Vector with equal projection onto two other vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Consider two vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ such that $|\vec{u}|\neq |\vec{v}| \neq 1$.

Consider a third vector $\vec{a}$ such that

$$\vec{a}.\vec{u}=\vec{a}.\vec{v}\neq 0$$

The question is to find $\vec{a}$.

Comment: I wrote $\vec{a}$ as linear combination of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ and tried to solve linear equation of the coefficients but got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_i$ and $v_i$ be the $i^{th}$ entry of $u,v$, respectively. This means that 
$$\sum u_i a_i = \sum v_ia_i $$
or
$$\sum_{i=1}^N (u_i-v_i) a_i = 0 $$
We have many choices here: EIther $a_i$'s are zero, but that's trivial. Instead we could pick $a_i = \frac{1}{u_i-v_i}$ if $u_i \neq v_i$ and a corresponding $a_j = -\frac{1}{u_j-v_j}$ if $u_j \neq v_j$. You do that repeatedly until the terms sum to zero. If one term is left out, you set that $a_i$ to zero.

Comment: So, for odd N, given $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, if $u_{i} \neq v_{i}$ for all $i$ then such an $\vec{a}$ won'e exist?

Comment: why wouldn't $a$ exist for odd $N$ ? @WInterfell

Comment: My apologies, i misinterpreted the above answer. There are many solutions for $\vec{a}$.